# Вывод значения по ключу в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php

Необходимо в ассоциативном массиве вывести значение по ключу:

```
$myArray = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1603201, 
    [name] => Масла, смазки и технические жидкости, 
    [alias] => masla-smazki-i-tehnicheskie-jidkosti/,
  ), 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 24,
    [name] => Моторное масло,
    [alias] => motornoe-maslo/,
  ),
  [2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 516,
    [name] => CEPSA,
    [alias] => motornoe-maslo/cepsa/ 
  ),
);
```

Нужно взять значение [name] у ключа [1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Совсем обленились чтоль о_О

```
echo $myArray[1]['name'];
```